# Error Installing PHP on Custom Compiled Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have downloaded and compiled Apache into my home directory, and it works on its own properly. The script I am using for this is [REDACTED] which downloads Apache, APR, and [REDACTED] to make an installation into whatever the current directory.

I have tried adding PHP support for this in a few ways. The first I tried was just to install the default php package with `apt-get` which can come with the Raspbian operating system (I believe this was some version of php5). I then removed that and installed php7.0 with libapache2-mod-php7.0 also using `apt-get`, but the results of both installations resulted in Apache not seeing the module. I also would like to stick with everything being encapsulated into the current directory (in this case it is ~ currently).

I then downloaded the php-7.2.4 package from php.net and compiled the source on my own with

```
configure --prefix=~/php --with-apxs2=~/apache/bin/apxs --enable-mbstring --with-openssl --enable-zip
make
make test
make install
cp php-production.ini ~/php/lib/php.ini
libtool --finish ~/php7/libs
~/apache/bin/apachectl restart
```

I can then run `~/php/bin/php -v` without problems.

In the `~/apache/conf/httpd.conf` the lines added for

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
...
<IfModule php7_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
...
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
</IfModule>
```

The PHP installer added the LoadModule line for me. I also do not have the `a2enmod` (or variants) as they seem to be specific to certain distributions.

Comment: Did you actually download and install or compile the apache php modules? installing the plain php package wont make apache work out of the box with php

Comment: I downloaded the zipped packages for Apache 2, APR, and PHP 7 respectively. Each was compiled on their own (APR during the Apache compile). The Apache and PHP installations seem to work independently of one another, but Apache cannot see PHP.

Comment: Shouldn't the module name for PHP be **php7apache2_4.so**?

Comment: I have double checked and there is not a php7apache2_4.so but there is a libphp7.so in ~/apache/modules/ (updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem after looking for the answer to Dave's comment. Between the last time I looked for libphp7.so and the time of the initial posting, I must have run the libtool and not restarted Apache. Everything is working as intended now. :)

Main post updated with command chain correction.